# Relate json column and extract data using the "with" eloquent method

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, eloquent-relationship

Im try development a chat and Im using laravel, have two tables
I need to get the chat with his users
table chats has: id, usuarios as json:

```
------------------------------------------
|id          |  usuarios json            |
------------------------------------------
|3           | [{user_id:1},{user_id:2}] |
|4           | [{user_id:7},{user_id:5}] |           
------------------------------------------

users: id, Name
------------------------------
|id          |  Name         |
------------------------------
|1           | Karls         |
|2           | Jon           |     
------------------------------

class Chat extends Model
{   
    // Test 1: return an Error list users relationsheaped  users.id with chat.id  
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
    }

    // Test 2: return an Error list users relationsheaped users.id with chat.isActive, i do it beacuse next test  
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id', 'isActive');
    }

    // Test 3: "the real way dosen't work" users return empty [], 
    // if i try change position 'usuarios->user_id' before and then 'id'  say error: Unknown column 'users.chat_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`chat_id` in (2))
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id', 'usuarios->user_id');
    }

    // Test 4: Unknown column 'users.JSON_CONTAINS(usuarios, concat('{"user_id":', id, '}'))' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`JSON_CONTAINS(usuarios, concat('{"user_id":', id, '}'))` in (2))  
    // if i change the position id, DB::raw... say: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,  DB::raw('JSON_CONTAINS(usuarios, concat(\'{"user_id":\', id, \'}\'))'), 'id' );
    }

    // Test 5:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT("$[", idx, "].user_id")) FROM JSON_TABLE(usuarios, "$[*]" COLUMNS idx FOR' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where id IN (SELECT JSON_VALUE(usuarios, CONCAT("$[", idx, "].user_id")) FROM JSON_TABLE(usuarios, "$[*]" COLUMNS idx FOR ORDINALITY) jt) and `users`.`id` in (2)
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id')
                    ->whereRaw('id IN (SELECT JSON_VALUE(usuarios, CONCAT("$[", idx, "].user_id")) FROM JSON_TABLE(usuarios, "$[*]" COLUMNS idx FOR ORDINALITY) jt)');
    }

    // Test 6:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, function ($query) {
            $query->select('users.*')
                ->from('users')
                ->join('chats', DB::raw('JSON_CONTAINS(chats.usuarios, concat(\'{"user_id":\', users.id, \'}\'))'), '=', DB::raw('1'))
                ->where('chats.id', '=', $this->id);
        });
    }

    // Test 7:   just add the next code say: Call to undefined relationship [users] on model [App\Chat].
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class)
                    ->whereHas('chats', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('chats.id', '=', $this->id)
                              ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(chats.usuarios, concat(\'{"user_id":\', users.id, \'}\'))');
                    });
    }
}
```

------------------------------- call the data

where i call method with the first Test

```
$chateado = Chat::with(['user'])->get();
```

return chats, but is not correct because return the chat.id 3 with user.id 3 this is error, where i need users.id in chats.usuarios:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "usuarios": [
            {
                "user_id": 1
            },
            {
                "user_id": 2
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "user 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I need to return the users is nested in chats.usuarios,
i tray with and without using use Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships; but not work. Is there anyone here or already went to chatgp? =( help me.

Comment: There's a package for this you can use https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations, but would be much simpler if you just create a pivot table between your user and chat table.